# How to prove (~Q -> ~P) - > (P -> Q) in Coq

Tags: logic, coq, coq-tactic

I am trying to prove (~Q -> ~P) - > (P -> Q) in coq, which is the reverse of the contrapositive theorem (P-> Q) (~Q -> ~P). Currently I was thinking about using the same logic of proving the contrapositive theorem like this:

unfold not. intros P Q. intros A B C.
apply B. apply A. apply C.

However I am stuck at the beginning. Maybe I need additional axioms to prove the reverse of the contrapositive theorem. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Require Import Classical.

Lemma myproof :  forall (P Q : Prop), (~Q -> ~P) -> (P -> Q) . 
unfold not. intros P Q. intros A B.
destruct (classic Q) as [Q_holds|NQ_holds].
apply Q_holds.
apply False_ind.
apply A.
apply NQ_holds.
apply B.
Qed.
```

Comment: What's reason for the Classical Q tho, and why I need to import the classical? I find out that if I remove the Classical keyword, the proof is wrong.

Comment: By default, the logic of Coq does not include the excluded middle. With the command `Require ...`. We add an axiom. Do `Check classic.`. Then your theorem is tagged as using an axiom. Do `Print Assumptions myproof.` after `Qed.`

Comment: the command `destruct ... ` just performs the case distinction on `Q` using the axiom `classic`.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much! This is really detailed!

Comment: yep, when doing proof in Coq, it is difficult at the beginning, exactly like learning to ride a bike.....

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you need some extra power (classical logic) to do this.
Put

```
Require Import Classical.
```

at the beginning of your file.
Now when you have a proposition `Q` with

```
destruct (classic Q) as [Q_holds|NQ_holds].
```

it creates two subgoals: one when `Q` holds and one when `~Q` holds.

Together with the theorem `False_ind` (that let you prove anything from `False`) it should be enough to conclude your proof.

Comment: Could you be specific about the False_ind theorem? What is it? I have never seen it before. Also it will be great if you could elaborate the whole proof process from the beginning

Comment: Ok lets start. What we want to prove  ```Lemma myproof :  forall (P Q : Prop), (~Q -> ~P) -> (P -> Q) .``` 
ok?

Comment: First line ```unfold not. intros P Q. intros A B.``` ok?

Comment: now we are struck. We cannot apply `A` nor `B`. So I do a case analysis on `Q` with `destruct (classic Q) as [Q_holds|NQ_holds].`

Comment: can you solve the first case when `Q` holds?

Comment: emm could tell me about it? The first case when Q holds

Comment: the command `destruct` should have creates two goals `(1/2)`  and `(2/2)`. The first goal has an assumption extra `Q_holds: Q`.

Comment: Yeah i get this, but how can I prove the case when Q holds?

Comment: you have to prove `Q` and you have as assumption `Q_holds: Q`

Comment: Now I see. Then what about the Q not hold case?

Comment: this is the tricky one. You have the assumption `NQ_holds : ~Q`  now with `A ` and `B` you have all the ingredients to prove `False`. ok?

Comment: Yeah three hypothesis A, B and the NQ_holds

Comment: The assumption `A` is capable to prove `False` if you are capable of  proving `~Q` (`Q -> False`) and `P`. This is what `A: (Q -> False) -> P -> False` says

Comment: I kinda see what's going on. I use the False_Ind. then apply the NQ_holds. Destruct A into Q-> False and P. Then simply apply NQ_holds for the sub first case, and apply B for the sub second case. Is that correct? The IDE shows correct tho...

Comment: yep I have posted my script so you can compare with yours